# how to stop and remove new release

Tags: windows-10-preview, windows-insider

My insider machine is currently running 15048 but fails to install 15055.  How can I remove the downloaded upgrade, because after a failed upgrade, I'm presented with a "A reboot is required to finalize installing 15055".  I want the computer to check upgrades, because 15061 is available, and my computer might have more luck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to c:\windows\softwaredistribution and delete all the content in the folder and reboot this way you'd delete the occurring updates and it will check automatically for new ones and downalod them.

Don't worry about deleting the folder it will recreate itself after the reboot.